# Received push notification count and show it on app badge icon android

Tags: java, android, push-notification, android-manifest

I want to create just like iOS. In iOS when every time you get a push notification, the app icon badge number will be increased by 1.

I found a git [ShortcutBadger](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger)

but when I try it did not work.

How Android can mimic iOS, every time you get a push notification, the app icon badge number will be increased by 1. And every time you click push notification, it goes to open the app and the app icon badge number will be decreased by 1?